# Patch a class method used in a view

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking, django-testing

I'm trying to test my view given certain responses from AWS. To do this I want to patch a class I wrote to return certain things while running tests.

```
 @patch.object(CognitoInterface, "get_user_tokens", return_value=mocked_get_user_tokens_return)


class TestLogin(TestCase):

    def test_login(self, mocked_get_user_tokens):
        print(CognitoInterface().get_user_tokens("blah", "blah")) # Works, it prints the patched return value

        login_data = {"email": "whatever@example.com", "password": "password"}
        response = self.client.post(reverse("my_app:login"), data=login_data)
```

Inside the view from "my_app:login", I call...

```
CognitoInterface().get_user_tokens(email, password)
```

But this time, it uses the real method. I want it to use the patched return here as well.

It seems my patch only applies inside the test file. How can I make my patch apply to all code during the test?

Edit: Never figured out why @patch.object wasn't working. I just used @patch("path.to.file.from.project.root.ClassName.method_to_patch").

Also, see: http://bhfsteve.blogspot.com/2012/06/patching-tip-using-mocks-in-python-unit.html

Comment: Got it to work with:  @patch("django_root.my_app.views.CognitoInterface.get_user_tokens")

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `CognitoInterface` is imported in the `views.py` earlier than the monkeypatching happens. You can check this by adding `print()` into the views where `CognitoInterface` is imported (or declared, it's not obvious from the amount of code here), and then another `print()` next to the monkeypatching.

If the monkeypatching happens latter, you have to either delay the import, or in worst case monkeypatch in both places.